# if condition in django template "{{ }}"

Tags: django, django-templates

Before showing a text I have to evaluate it.

Instead of

```
{% if value %} text_true {% else %} text_false {% endif %}
```

Are there anything like:

```
{{ text_true if value else text_false }}
```

Comment: This is not possible in the default django template language

Answer (score 2):

For the example in your question, you can use the [`yesno`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno) filter

```
{{ value|yesno:'text_true,text_false' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with this exact syntax, but there are the `default` and `default_if_none` template filters. Those may be what you're looking for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#default